# Extracting Map<K, Multiset<V>> from Stream of Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have Stream of Stream of Words(This format is not set by me and cannot be changed). For ex

```
Stream<String> doc1 = Stream.of("how", "are", "you", "doing", "doing", "doing");
Stream<String> doc2 = Stream.of("what", "what", "you", "upto");
Stream<String> doc3 = Stream.of("how", "are", "what", "how");
Stream<Stream<String>> docs = Stream.of(doc1, doc2, doc3);
```

I'm trying to get this into a structure of `Map<String, Multiset<Integer>>` (or its corresponding stream as I want to process this further), where the key `String` is the word itself and the `Multiset<Integer>` represents the number of that word appearances in each document (0's should be excluded). Multiset is a google guava class(not from java.util.).

For example:

```
how   -> {1, 2}  // because it appears once in doc1, twice in doc3 and none in doc2(so doc2's count should not be included)
are   -> {1, 1}  // once in doc1 and once in doc3
you   -> {1, 1}  // once in doc1 and once in doc2
doing -> {3}     // thrice in doc3, none in others 
what  -> {2,1}   // so on
upto  -> {1}
```

What is a good way to do this in Java 8 ?

I tried using a flatMap , but the inner Stream is greatly limiting the options of I have.

Comment: `MultiSet` seems like a strange choice, not only would it inhibit the same frequency of occurrence in different documents, but the order is undefined, so you wouldn't know which count belonged to which document.

Comment: The Value of the map can be a list of MultiSets, or a Map<String, Integer>

Comment: @JornVernee .. I'm okay with losing the order. That is the reason for choosing it over List. AFAIK, we can have same frequency of occurrence in different documents with MultiSet right ? For MultiSet of {1,1,1} is perfectly valid

Comment: The [main use case of Multiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) is using `.count(Object)` to get the number of times an element appears, which doesn't seem necessary with the word counts themselves. If you just need the values in any order with duplicates allowed, List is still the best solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 Map<String, List<Long>> map = docs.flatMap(
            inner -> inner.collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(map);

// {upto=[1], how=[1, 2], doing=[3], what=[2, 1], are=[1, 1], you=[1, 1]}
```

Comment: Was going to post something very similar. The formatting could use some improvement though.

Comment: I've restructured it a bit. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, Multiset<Integer>> result = docs
        .map(s -> s.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashMultiset::create)))
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Multiset.Entry::getElement,
                Collectors.mapping(Multiset.Entry::getCount,
                        Collectors.toCollection(HashMultiset::create))));

// {upto=[1], how=[1, 2], doing=[3], what=[1, 2], are=[1 x 2], you=[1 x 2]}
```

Multiset is useful for getting the word count, but not really necessary for storing the counts. If you're fine with `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, just replace the last line with `Collectors.toList())));`.

Or, since you're using Guava anyway, why not a ListMultimap?

```
ListMultimap<String, Integer> result = docs
        .map(s -> s.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashMultiset::create)))
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(ArrayListMultimap::create,
                (r, e) -> r.put(e.getElement(), e.getCount()),
                Multimap::putAll);

// {upto=[1], how=[1, 2], doing=[3], what=[2, 1], are=[1, 1], you=[1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Guava, you could take advantage of its utilities to work with streams. Same with the `Table` structure. Here's the code:

```
Table<String, Long, Long> result =
    Streams.mapWithIndex(docs, (doc, i) -> doc.map(word -> new SimpleEntry<>(word, i)))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Tables.toTable(
            Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, p -> 1L, Long::sum, HashBasedTable::create));
```

Here I'm using the [`Streams.mapWithIndex`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#mapWithIndex-java.util.stream.Stream-com.google.common.collect.Streams.FunctionWithIndex-) method to assign an index to each inner stream. Within the map function, I'm transforming each word to a pair that consists of the word and the index, so that I can later know to which document the word belongs.

Then, I'm flat-mapping the pairs `(word, index)` of all documents to one stream, and finally, I'm collecting all the pairs to a Guava `Table` by means of the [`Tables.toTable`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#toTable-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) collector. The row is the word, the column is the document (represented by the index) and the value is the count of words for each document (I'm assigning `1L` to each different `(word, index)` pair and using `Long::sum` to merge collisions).

You have all the info you need in the `result` table, but if you still need a `Map<String, Multiset<Integer>>`, you could do it this way:

```
Map<String, Multiset<Long>> map = Maps.transformValues(
    result.rowMap(),
    m -> HashMultiset.create(m.values()));
```

Note: you need Guava 21 for this to work.

Comment: you could replace `Pair` with `new SimpleEntry<>(word, i)`. Also notice that OP does not care which doc index entries came from: he does not want `how={0=1, 2=2}`, but `how={1,2}`

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for your feedback. I replaced `Pair` with `SimpleEntry`. Regarding the doc index, you can use `rowMap()` on the table and then use `Maps.transformValues` to lazily change the table to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution by [AbacusUtil](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil):

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> m = Stream.of(doc1, doc2, doc3)
          .flatMap(d -> d.toMultiset().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap2());
```